# How to add information to registry.hub.docker.com?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I pushed a container onto my project in docker registry hub,

there are two tabs Information and Tags,

how could I add the Information for my container ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information tab is filled when you set up an auto build that builds a Dockerfile that is hosted on your github account. It simply takes the README.md contents of your github project.

The tags tab is filled when you configure your auto build to assign tags to different branches of your github project.

As an example please have a look at [this](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/h3nrik/registry-ldap-auth/) docker hub page and [this](https://github.com/g17/registry-ldap-auth) github project.

Comment: For non-automatically building repositories, you need to edit the Information tab yourself. The Tags tab will get filled with the tags you `docker push`.